# How to test the performance of parallel processing with Spliterators in Java

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, spliterator

Suppose we are given a data structure that implements a spliterator as well. What is the boilerplate code for testing whether parallel processing using that spliterator is actually better than sequential processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test the spliterator itself you may create a sequential and parallel stream and reduce it with simple reduction operation with minimal overhead. For example:

```
@Benchmark
public sequential(Blackhole bh) {
    bh.consume(StreamSupport.stream(myContainer.spliterator(), false).reduce((a, b) -> a));
}

@Benchmark
public parallel(Blackhole bh) {
    bh.consume(StreamSupport.stream(myContainer.spliterator(), true).reduce((a, b) -> a));
}
```

Usually it's more critical to check whether your parallel spliterator works correctly for any sequence of `trySplit/tryAdvance/forEachRemaining` calls. Before testing the speed it's a good idea to test thoroughly for correctness.

Also probably a good idea is to create the test which is closer to real life. Think up how your data structure will be used in production code and create the test which implements such real example in parallel and in sequential. Such results would be more relevant to users of your data structure.

Comment: Thank you. Accepted. What library is `Benchmark` from? Will it neatly print the duration of the annotated method?

Comment: @coderodde, it's [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). Surely it will print. It requires some learning (study the examples on the linked page), but it's cool.

Answer (score 0):

While [Tagir Valeev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31760592/1362755) already covered the basics you should keep the following in mind:

Parallel processing can be faster two reasons

- the sheer size of the data structure limiting what a single core can process due to memory bandwidth constraints
- the intermediate/collector steps in the pipeline being sufficiently expensive that executing them in parallel amortizes the parallelization overhead

The latter can already pay off at much smaller data structure sizes and possibly even with inefficient spliterator behavior.

Ideally you should test both, because asymptotically good performance does not mean it performs well on the near end of the curve.